# Use Arrayformula to show two times each cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have a row with dates, eg:
date1 | date2 | date3

I already use arrayformula to reference this row in another sheet,  but now i need to duplicate each date like this:
date1 | date1 | date2 | date2 | date3 | date3 |

Is this possible to do with google sheets formulas?
i tried =arrayformula({ A1:C1 , A1:C 1}) but the output is:

date1 | date2 | date3 | date1 | date2 | date3

What i need is far more complex and i can easily solve it with a script, but i wonder if it's possible to do it only by formula (without it turning overly complicated)

Here's the link for an example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15gH4aRcto-8LQh2ODJLtpD1yFCNb9YIP-P5ac7Fz4N4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, an alternative solution could be ...

```
=ArrayFormula(split(join(char(9), rept(A1:E1&char(9),2)), char(9)))
```

Make sure to apply the same date format as in the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Please try, in ColumnB and copied across to suit:

```
=ArrayFormula(offset($A1,,int((column()-2)/2)))
```

It is an array formula but works the same non-array.

Comment: That is very interesting. I still cant understand what is happening exactly lol but it does give the desired output when copied into a row. I see Arrayformula is actually not needed there.
There is still a problem though, and the idea behind using arrayformula was for the output to automatically expand when adding new dates to the base row. (For which i'd reference a bigger range, ending many colums after the last date)